# Pause/Suspend multiple Threads at the same time then resume

Tags: java, multithreading, button, pause

Yes this is an assignment question first off
I'm creating multiple threads for a Elevator Simulation and I'm at the point where I now have the threads running but now must interrupt them. I have tried using access modifiers to change when the "Pause" button is pressed

```
eg: While(true){
     if(!Paused){
      *run code*
      }
     else {
       thread.sleep(10000);
      System.out.println("Paused");
     }}
```

But it doesn't work, I've tried calling the elevator and pausing it directly, but what I think my problem is, is I am not accessing the Thread, I'm accessing the Elevator Object and not the Thread itself.

```
eg: public void aWait() {
    for (Elevator e : elevators)
    {            
        e.pauseThread();
}}
```

Just for context my runnable is implemented like this :

```
eg:     public void run() {
        while (true) {
            while (!paused) {
                    moveToNextDestination();
                    process();
                    System.out.println(Building.getStatusReport());}}}
```

And my process is like this

```
eg: public void process() {
    Person person;
    for (Elevator elevator : Building.elevators) {
        if (elevator.isAvailable() && (elevator.getCurrentFloor() == 0)) {
            while (Building.queue.size() > 0 && elevator.hasCapacity()) {
                person = Building.queue.get(0);
                elevator.loadPerson(person);
                Building.queue.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really need help with the elevator itself just managing the Thread, any advice on how to manage this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not have a class the has something like a boolean running. And each thread can check if running is true or false and perform the appropriate action.

Comment: You could use a monitor lock or `Reentract` lock to "pause" a thread (when the appropriate flag is set) which would then allow you to "wake" them at some point in the future

Comment: Maybe I don't get the problem, but shouldn't you use `wait`  and `notify` (resp. `notifyAll`)? But from your sample code, I can see only a single thread that you're working on. Where does the multithreading happen? Or you use a `Semaphore` like MadProgrammer suggested.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing and how does it  differ from the behavior you want?  Also, please provide code that can be compiled and run.  You can strip out the elevator behavior, but you're leaving out a lot that we need to see in order to understand the concurrency issues.